# Subcaption package not doing what I want it to do

Tags: subfloats

I want to build a figure with 5 subfigures inside. The code I have goes as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mi1}
\footnotesize{\caption{masa=$(0,0203 \pm 0,0001)\;kg$, $m=(2,43\pm 0,01)\; s^{-2}$, $b= (1,22 \pm 0,08)\; s^{-1}$, $R^2=0,990$. }}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mi2}
\footnotesize{\caption{masa=$(0,0401 \pm 0,0001)\;kg$, $m=(5,20\pm 0,03)\; s^{-2}$, $b= (3,6 \pm0,1)\; s^{-1}$, $R^2=0,990$.}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mi3}
\footnotesize{\caption{masa=$(0,0503 \pm 0,0001)\;kg$, $m=(6,44\pm0,04)\; s^{-2}$, $b= (8,7 \pm0,1)\; s^{-1}$, $R^2=0,987$.}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mi4}
\footnotesize{\caption{masa=$(0,0704 \pm 0,0001)\;kg$, $m=(9,32\pm0,05)\; s^{-2}$, $b= (11,9 \pm0,1)\; s^{-1}$, $R^2=0,987$.}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mi5}
\footnotesize{\caption{masa=$(0,0904 \pm 0,0001)\;kg$, \\ $m=(12,14\pm0,08)\; s^{-2}$, $b= (8,8 \pm \\ 0,2)\; s^{-1}$, $R^2=0,987$.}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Se representan las velocidades angulares que adquiere la placa cebra en función del tiempo cuando el sistema se encuentra acelerado angularmente por una masa variable que ejerce un torque a una distancia de $(0,01998 \pm 0,00001) \;m$  con respecto al centro de masa. En rojo se superpone la recta de regresión calculada por el método de cuadrados mínimos con su pendiente $m$.}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is with the last subfigure. I want to put it in the middle but if I use \linewidth, the caption of the subfigure begins at the beginning of the page and not where the subfigure actually is. [image: This image shows the problem I'm facing.]

Could someone help out with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the width of the last `subfigure` to `\textwidth`, set that as well to `0.4\textwidth`, add `\centering` at the start of the `figure`, and perhaps an `\hfill` between the subfigures that are on the same line.

Some other comments:

- `\footnotesize` is not a macro that takes an argument, so to limit its effect you should use `{\footnotsize ...\par}`, not `\footnotesize{..}`. However, you shouldn't be using it for every subcaption the way you have, to change the font properties of subcaptions use `\captionsetup`, as in the code below.
- Units should be written in upright font, not in the default math font, so `$m$` for example is wrong. A very nice package for typesetting numbers with units (or just numbers, or just units) is `siunitx`. I modified your captions to use this below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize,justification=raggedright}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  separate-uncertainty=true
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{%
$\text{masa}=\SI{0,0203 \pm 0,0001}{\kg}$, $m=\SI{2,43\pm 0,01}{\per\square\s}$, $b= \SI{1,22 \pm 0,08}{\per\s}$, $R^2=\num{0,990}$. }
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\text{masa}=\SI{0,0401 \pm 0,0001}{\kg}$, $m=\SI{5,20\pm 0,03}{\per\square\s}$, $b= \SI{3,6 \pm0,1}{\per\s}$, $R^2=\num{0,990}$.}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\text{masa}=\SI{0,0503 \pm 0,0001}{\kg}$, $m=\SI{6,44\pm0,04}{\per\second\squared}$, $b= \SI{8,7 \pm0,1}{\per\s}$, $R^2=\num{0,987}$.}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\text{masa}=\SI{0,0704 \pm 0,0001}{\kg}$, $m=\SI{9,32\pm0,05}{\per\square\s}$, $b= \SI{11,9 \pm0,1}{\per\s}$, $R^2=\num{0,987}$.}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\text{masa}=\SI{0,0904 \pm 0,0001}{\kg}$,  $m=\SI{12,14\pm0,08}{\per\square\s}$, $b= \SI{8,8 \pm 0,2}{\per\s}$, $R^2=\num{0,987}$.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Se representan las velocidades angulares que adquiere la placa cebra en función del tiempo cuando el sistema se encuentra acelerado angularmente por una masa variable que ejerce un torque a una distancia de \SI{0,01998 \pm 0,00001}{\m}  con respecto al centro de masa. En rojo se superpone la recta de regresión calculada por el método de cuadrados mínimos con su pendiente \si{m}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JuanManuelPerezBertoldi I just edited my answer a bit.

Comment: In the caption of the figure as a whole, why is there a space between the two nines in 0,01998 \pm 0,00001 when using the \SI command? Is that the format convention for academic writing?

Comment: @JuanManuelPerezBertoldi Probably depends on whose conventions you're looking at. Sorry, didn't notice that. By default, `siunitx` will group numbers with five digits or more into groups of three, with a small space between, you can turn that off by adding `group-digits=false` to the `\sisetup`.